# Predatory publisher

Tags: publications, disreputable-publishers

I work on political ecology and I currently writing up my thesis. Inadvertently I sent around 3000 words to a conference on "tribals" in Kerala organised by a TISS professor with no address or landline. I withdrew the paper but fear misuse. How can I work on it for publication now?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about a predatory publisher until you encounter a predatory publisher. Assume good faith!

Answer (score 1):

Do you suspect that the conference is fraudulent, or is it genuine and only the organising professor's contact details missing?

Reason being, TISS is a reputed institute and you shouldn't have difficulty in finding a faculty member's contact details. If you suspect the professor's name is being used fraudulently, you should bring that to his/her notice. If you do find an instance of misuse and want to fight it, having a respected witness will be helpful.

You should also keep a copy of the conference brochure, all communication with them, especially acknowledgement of abstract/paper receipt, withdrawal acceptance and so on. If you are in an academic institute, do consult your supervisor or a senior faculty member for more specific action.